# CheckboxListTile state not changing when clicked inspite of calling setState

Tags: flutter

I am creating a List of checkboxes using ListView and CheckboxListTile as below. However, when I click or unclick on an item, the CheckboxListTile does not update and reflect the check or uncheck.

The code creating the ListView is below:

```
  void _showDialog(context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Material(
            child: ListView(
                children: this.selectionList.map((e) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  value: e.isSelected,
                  title: Text(e.name),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      e.isSelected = value ?? false;
                    });
                  });
            }).toList()),
          );
        });
  }
```

Also including the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipevault/models/user_profile.dart';

class MultiSelectComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Interest> displayList; //initial values are marked as selected=true

  MultiSelectComponent({Key? key, this.displayList = const <Interest>[]})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiSelectComponentState createState() => _MultiSelectComponentState();
}

class _MultiSelectComponentState extends State<MultiSelectComponent> {
  List<Interest> selectionList = <Interest>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      this.selectionList = List.from(widget.displayList);
    });
  }

  void _showDialog(context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Material(
            child: ListView(
                children: this.selectionList.map((e) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  value: e.isSelected,
                  title: Text(e.name),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      e.isSelected = value ?? false;
                    });
                  });
            }).toList()),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _showDialog(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1.2),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Select"),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Wrap(children: [
            ...selectionList
                .where((element) => element.isSelected)
                .map((e) => Chip(
                      label: Text(e.name),
                      onDeleted: () {
                        setState(() {
                          e.isSelected = false;
                        });
                      },
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ]),
        ]);
  }
}

class Interest {
  final String type, name;
  final int id;
  bool isSelected;

  Interest(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.type,
      this.isSelected = false});

  Interest.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          id: json['id']! as int,
          type: json['type']! as String,
          name: json['name']! as String,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': this.id,
      'type': this.type,
      'name': this.name,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the content of `showDialog`'s builder to a separate `StatefulWidget`.